Attached image temporary files of Rails Action Text stays stored on disk
I'm using Active Text in my project, but I notice something strange.  When I try to attach an image, image is shown in the editor and it's uploaded immediately, without I click in save button for sending html form.
A record is saved on the table "active_storage_blobs" of the database:

Then if I cancel the form submission, the image remains saved on the table of database. This causes unnecessary files to remain stored on the disk.

How do I delete those files on the table and on disk?

Does this answer your question? How to clean up ActiveStorage record and storage folder of development environment?

It's not really that strange. ActiveStorage comes with a Javascript component that does file uploads asyncrously which gives a much better user experience and this is exactly how its supposed to work.  Otherwise the entire form submission "hangs" until the file uploads are complete. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads
